# Problem assigning output of a command to a variable

Tags: bash

I have written a script that uses the below to display the amount of characters in "$var1"

```
echo -n "$var1" | wc -c
```

This displays the numeric value without an issue. However rather than display the value I wish to assign it to a the variable $char in order to then apply various conditions.

```
char=$(-n "$var1" | wc -c)
echo $char
```

However this produces the following error.

-n: command not found

Comment: `$( -n ....)` tries to invoke a command named `-n`, and you don't have such a command. Note that everything between `$(` and the corresponding  `)` is run as a command in a child process.

Comment: For getting the numbe of characters in `var1`, do a `echo ${#var1}`. No need to involve a child process here.

Comment: one step further: `char=${#var1}`, so need to invoke a sub/child process